# Flutter show/hide widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to show a widget onFinished countdown timer but I can't seem to make it work.
I've added var reqPIN = false;

And here is my code:

```
        children [
         Countdown(
            seconds: 3,
            build: (_, double time) =>
                RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                    text: 'Reset PIN in ',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme.labelStyle?.color
                    ),
                    children: <TextSpan>[
                      TextSpan(
                        text: time.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF2481CF),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      )),
                      TextSpan(text: ' sec',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme.labelStyle?.color
                      ))
                    ]
                  ),
                ),
            onFinished: () {
              setState(() {
                reqPIN = true;
              });
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(
            child: Visibility(
              visible: reqPIN,
              child: Text('Resend PIN',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black
              ),),
            ),
          )
        ]
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Where is the 'reqPIN' variable defined? Let me know Stateful code include this code.

Comment: Can you include the full widget, that will reproduce the same issue?

Comment: Post a full or bare minimum code, which can produce the same result

Comment: I've posted the full code [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241943/discussion-between-kamal-nathani-and-aufa) @iamdipanshus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onlySelectedBorderPinPut()` is not getting called on `setState`...

to fix this, you can wrap your RichText with a Column, and add your Resend button there, you won't need to have a reqPin bool for managing the state, simply handle it with the remaining time like below

```dart
Countdown(
  seconds: 3,
  build: (_, double time) => Column(
    children: [
       RichText(
       ...
       ),
       Visibility(
          visible: time == 0,
          child: SizedBox(
                   child: Text('Resend PIN',
                   style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black
                 )
              ),
           ),
         ),
      ],
   ),
),
```

Comment: glad it worked, plz upvote if it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
if (reqPIN)
   SizedBox(
     child: Text('Resend PIN', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
    ),
```

Comment: where should I put it?

Comment: Replace below code with i sent above.
`SizedBox(
            child: Visibility(
              visible: reqPIN,
              child: Text('Resend PIN',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black
              ),),
            ),
          )`

Comment: I've tried it but still didn't work

Comment: Did you checked `onFinished` function is called or not?

Comment: yes, i've tried print('request code') in the onFinished and it worked

Comment: Attach full code of this file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241943/discussion-between-kamal-nathani-and-aufa).